# Countries with Fat Tax on people

Tags: law, international-law, public-health

Which countries have implemented a "fat tax" on people with obesity, or high body fat percentage? I am talking about the human person themselves, and not a tax on food like sugar, oil, dairy etc.

Japan is the only country I read about. Are there any others?

[Countries That Taxes people for being too fat](https://medium.com/illumination-curated/the-country-that-taxes-people-for-being-too-fat-356cacdc1d32#:%7E:text=It%20might%20come%20as%20no,employer%20on%20an%20annual%20basis.)

Comment: The article itself basically says that there are no other such countries.

Comment: hi @ohwilleke just wondering if maybe the article is outdated, or missing information due to research, sometimes articles at Medium can miss information, however it is dated 2021

Comment: That might be a difficult concept in a country that is relativly litigious. Suppose, as some have suggested, that the prevalence of obesity in the US is due to faulty advice from government run health agencies. The law suits could produce a lot of friction.

Comment: I don't blame the OP for questioning the article's reliability after reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are none.

Indeed the article rather misrepresents how the system in Japan works - its a public health initiative that provides tax incentives and penalties to companies and local governments, through their health insurance, that monitor and improve the levels of obesity among their employees or residents. It's not a "tax on fat people".  The aim was to get 65% involvement between age 40 and 75 , which of course means that 35% of eligible people aren't involved.  And the tax penalties for failing to participate fall on companies, not individuals. Since the cost of weight reduction measures falls on insurance, and since most health insurance is provided thought regional government, the effect is that local governments prioritise spending on obesity control.

Many other countries (UK, Denmark, parts of India) have fat or sugar taxes on certain foods.